# OpenMP: how to optimize a thread-safe hash-table

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp, hashtable

I'm trying to make a hash table (`unordered_map`)  thread-safe, for a performance-critical application. I'm using OpenMP to handle multithreading. The first solution I tried was to make all access to the hash-table `critical`, but this ended up lowering the performance of threads so much that the parallel version wasn't faster anymore. I then came with the following idea: make 100 separate hash-tables, initialized to empty set, and store them in an array. Use some hash function to map the key to the range `[0, 1, ..., 99]`, and store the value in the corresponding hash table. Here is a pseudo-code to demonstrate this idea:

```
auto hash_vec = vector<unordered_map<int,int> >(100); 
int prime = 534161472029; // some big prime
int rand_int = rand();  // random int used for 
int simple_hash(int v) {
     return (rand_int * v) % prime;
}
void safe_write(int key, int val) {
    int h = simple_hash(key) % 100;
    hash_vec[h][key] = val; // must be made safe
}
int safe_read() {
     int h = simple_hash(key) % 100;
     int val = hash_vec[h][key]; // must be made safe
     return val;
}
```

so the idea is that if value of `h` is not the same, there won't be any race condition. For example, if `simple_hash(k1)` is not equal to `simple_hash(k2)`, a simultaneous call to `safe_write(k1,v1)` and `safe_write(k2,v2)` won't cause any thread to wait. Is such a thing possible? If not, is there a better way to ensure performance is not too compromised?

Comment: Minor note (not commenting on design in general): Usually, you'd make the array a power of two in size, so you can use a cheap mask instead of more expensive remaindering. Make the array length 128, and you can just do `simple_hash(key) & 0x7f`. With a constant divisor, it's possible the compiler can find non-division ways to accomplish the division for some constants (don't know off-hand if 100 is one of them), but a simple bit mask is as cheap as it gets.

Comment: Your solution seems like a good idea for me. Simply, to protect the access, you can create an array of `omp_lock`, one per `hash_vec` and then protect them individually. That should reduce dramatically the congestion between threats.

Comment: If your hardware has support for speculative locks, then you can just use a single, speculative lock around the whole hashtable. See the section on lock hints in https://www.openmp.org/wp-content/uploads/SC18-BoothTalks-Cownie.pdf which does exactly that for std::unordered_map

Comment: @Gilles You don't necessarily need one lock/hash-bucket. You can equally use a differently sized array of locks and hash into that using the bucket-index as the key. That will have more contention (depending on the ratio of the number of hash-buckets and the size of the lock-table), but can save memory which may matter.

Comment: Not sure how the hash table is implemented, but constantly writing into it from different threads, even without locks and given that no data races occur, is still going to be very slow because of an effect known as *false sharing*. When one thread modifies data that is also in the cache of one or more of the other CPU cores, their caches get invalidated, which means next time the threads running there access the table, data must be read from an upper-level cache, which is slow(er). False sharing can easily turn a very fast sequential algorithm into a slow as turtle parallel one.